# Why the java process is not closing when the app is finished?

Tags: java, linux, windows, cmd, sh

I write a java program which is run in the background. And it works fine,it does what is waited from it.
I write a `bat` file in windows to run it.

```
@echo off
start .\jre7\bin\java.exe -jar ".\my_jar.jar"
exit
```

When I run this `.bat` file I can see it on **task manager** and It works and when it finished , the java.exe process is closed on the **task manager**.
It works fin on *Windows*
But When I run it on linux in .sh file,
It the java program works fine because It does what I wait from it ,but on the *Sytem Monitor*
the *java* process is not closing. I want it to close by itself like *Windows*.
in sh file:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/app/myfolder/java/jre1.7.0_51" 
export I_HOME="/app/myfolder/code" 

cd $I_HOME 

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar my_jar.jar
RStat=$?
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also terminate the application with:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: I didnot call *System.exit(0)* but why I need it , because in windows it dissappear when the app is finished?

Answer (score 1):

Its definitely not normal for it to terminate gracefully on windows and not on linux.
Your jar could just be hanging on linux due to differences in whatever native libraries you're using, have you tried calling System.exit()?

Comment: I didnot call *System.exit()?* but why I need it , because in windows it dissappear when the app is finished?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why you would need it. The most common case is with a large or complex application with many threads that need the closure on an application-level as they may not have insight into each other. Otherwise it's just good practice, you should call System.exit(0) where your application is supposed to terminate gracefully, and define error codes otherwise. It is impossible for java -jar to hang on linux and not on windows, its your jar itself that is hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your thread to a daemon?

```
public final void setDaemon(boolean on)
```

From the JavaDoc:

> Marks this thread as either a daemon thread or a user thread. The Java Virtual Machine exits when the only threads running are all daemon threads

Comment: thanks for answer, ı do not understand where can I set it, I do not set it. And in windows it is running but in linux it behaves different, is it normal

Comment: What's "your thread"? You certainly don't want the main-thread to be a daemon. But it would certainly be nice to know if the OP has any additional threads running that are non-daemon - but why only on Linux?